# Optimisation: (\\[^$&\\] | [^$&\\])*

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long Regex (JavaScript), and it contains the following construct:

```
((?:\\[^$&\\])|(?:[^$&\\]))*
```

**The regex says:**

Match any String, that doesn't contain the symbols `$` `&` and `\`

The symbol `\` is allowed, if it's used for escaping. But only, if it doesn't escape one of the forbidden symbols.

**Here's a simple match-example:**

`this`&`IsAText\nWithNewLines`$`And`\$`Forbidden`\\ `Symbols`

I wonder if it's possible to optimise this regular expression. This is only a little example, the actual regex I'm using is bigger due to many different symbols I have to write twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just `\\?[^$&\\]`?  Optional `\` followed by your negate group.

It would make the whole thing `(\\?[^$&\\])*`